# How to target a Django form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I'd like to target my django form with jQuery, but differently of a html select tag, I don't have a class to do that.

Could someone help me?

Ps: I'm a beginner on programming.

```
<!-- Selection Box -->
    <div>
        <form action=""  method="post">{% csrf_token %}              
             {{selectfield}} <!-- my form -->
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
    <!-- End of Selection Box -->

    <!-- Jquery Select2 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.target').select2({ placeholder: "Select here", maximumSelectionSize: 100});
        })
    </script>    
    <!-- End of JQuery Select2 -->
```

Comment: when forms renders then select has some class, right? so you can target it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own class inside of forms.py. For example:

```
 selectfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=_('Field'),
                                  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'myselect'}),
                                  queryset= CoolDeveloper.objects.all(),
                                  required=False)
```

Comment: @Filipe great! please mark then the answer as solved